# How to use FastCGI to send an image

Tags: perl, apache, fastcgi

I'm using Apache mod_fcgid and FastCGI under Apache. I'm trying to write a Perl fcgi to send images to the client browser. I googled sending an image file in perl FastCGI script, but found nothing.

For example, if a client requests `<http://mydomain.com/perl-cgi/123.jpg>`, perl-cgi will get the request and respond with resized 123.jpg (this image located on the Apache server), but how does it send the image? I found all the samples on internet sends plain text/html, didn't find out how to send images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your specific problem? Are you asking about the content-type? Are you asking how to read the image file and then send it to the client? You question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my ambiguous expression, found the solution already. My previous question is how to return an image as response to client browser, and I googled wrong direction, I searched keyword for fastcgi. Actually it's a common knowledge of CGI. At last I just use: print("Content-Type:image/jpg\r\n\r\n"); copy "filepath" \*STDOUT; that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copying files from the filesystem yourself an echo'ing them back to Apache, why not use something like https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ . All your response includes is standard headers and a special X-Sendfile header. The server module reads the file from the filesystem and returns it to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if it works well with perl script. My application is not php, what I'm doing is just using Perl and imagemagik to resize the image and pass it back, so a easy script is enough, don't need any advanced function :)